# gwibber twitter authorization problem

Tags: gwibber, ssl, twitter

I've tried to authorize my twitter with gwibber before (I've reinstalled ubuntu because some other problem), now I can't authorize any twitter account, it just tells me "SSL is required" and I have SSL installed in my system, or do I have the wrong SSL library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a fix over [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1286639). Basically, you have to make a few edits to some of the gwibber python scripts. Here's a copy of the instructions:

> File /usr/share/gwibber/plugins/twitter/gtk/twitter/**init**.py
>
> Line 78 and 144 - Needs to be "https" where it states "http"
>
> File /usr/share/gwibber/plugins/twitter/**init**.py
>
> Line 401 - Needs to be "https" where it states "http"

The fix will probably show up in the an ubuntu update at some point.